# Getting the actual http request from HttpWebRequst Object in C#

Tags: c#, http, web

I have a very simple app that sends an HttpWebRequest and gets a response. I need to know the exact request sent to the server. Is it possible?

Something like this:

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32
```

Comment: If this is just for one-off diagnostics, have you looked at using Wireshark?

Comment: Consider using the http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ web debugger to see the request, assuming you only need to do this during debugging.

Comment: I am not familiar with both of them! I will take a llok at them! Thank you. But I am always looking for more simple ways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a basic web server with the [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx).  The example shows how to do this.  Then, point your HttpWebRequest to that server and see the results.

Comment: Would you please provide more details on how to get the exact requst using TcpListener object?

Comment: The example code of the TcpListener link puts the request into the `data` string, then it prints it to the console.  (It is broken into chunks, but you can re-assemble it easily.)